# Css element not in shape when appearing in mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

Am having issues with Mozilla Firefox, i have two divs both positioned absolute in a parent div, when my javascript display the element, it is displayed on top each other in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge but it is displayed side by side in Mozilla Firefox, I don't know why this is happening but it is giving me a very hard time.

Html:

```css
    #listStudentDialog {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin-top: 120px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
    #dialogLoader {
        display: flex;
        height: inherit;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        transform: scale(1);
        transition: all 0.35s linear;
    }
    .loaderInfo {
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
        z-index: 70;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        background: #f9f3f3;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        transition: all 0.35s linear;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    #listStudentLoader {
        margin: auto;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        transform: scale(1);
        -webkit-transition: transform 0.35s linear;
        -moz-transition: transform 0.35s linear;
        transition: transform 0.35s linear;
        animation-duration: 10s;
        animation-name: none;
    }
```

```html
<div id="listStudentDialog" style="opacity: 1;">
        <div id="dialogLoader">
            <div class="loaderInfo icon-success">
                <span class="path1"></span>
                <span class="path2"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="loader" id="listStudentLoader"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the code you posted does not produce the output you claim in any browser at all

Comment: now that someone has edited your question, my comment looks stupid because there's no indication of what you claim to get in any browser!!

Comment: The font i used is not attached in this post, i dont know how to attach that here

Comment: how do you use it in your web page? do that

Comment: I created a font face in css and linked it to a font located in my computer, the font contains svg images that are meant to be displayed